# asp.net core 1.0 cross-compilation possible?

Tags: asp.net-core, cross-compiling, asp.net-core-1.0

is cross-compilation possible? 
Compile a application in windows and target linux?
If yes it should then be possible to create a docker image, using the correct template, from windows that runs in linux just by adding the build output?

Thanks

Comment: .NET core helps to achieve this. Write apps in windows & target them to .NET Core platform. .NET core is open cross platform technology. You are right about docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Two possibilities:

1. Portable Applications: You need to install .NET Core on that target machine. That is the same bytecode just executed somewhere else.
2. Self-contained Application: During the build you specify the target platforms as "runtimes" in the project.json of your projet. `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, `dotnet restore -r ubuntu.14.04-x64`.

You have to be aware: Both solutions are compiled to bytecode. The second option will bundle the .NET Core runtime along with your output so you do not need a local installation (that is what you want for docker).

There is another step further, called .NET Native (https://github.com/dotnet/corert) which is not yet well supported (it is early beta). This would ahead-of-time compile your source code to native executables. I am not aware whether that use case currently targets cross-compilation. But for now, the normal bytecode execution and JITing must be sufficient.